# Efficient way to bin data ranges in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, binning

I have several hundred variables in a data frame which need to be binned into buckets.

Currently, I'm using code similar to the following:

```
idx <- list()
idx[[1]] <- which(df$myVariable < 628 & df$myVariable >= 0)
idx[[2]] <- which(df$myVariable < 774 & df$myVariable >= 628)
idx[[3]] <- which(df$myVariable < 885 & df$myVariable >= 774)
idx[[4]] <- which(df$myVariable <= Inf & df$myVariable >= 4819)
idx[[5]] <- which(df$myVariable < 0)
df$myVariable[idx[[1]]] = 1
df$myVariable[idx[[2]]] = 2
df$myVariable[idx[[3]]] = 3
df$myVariable[idx[[4]]] = 4
df$myVariable[idx[[5]]] = 0
```

In reality, there are 21 ranges of values for each of the variables, and the cut points may vary between the variables. So, in full, this code is over 30,000 lines long (I have a script which generates it).

Is there a better way to represent this code? Ideally it would make use of dplyr, since I intend to run this code in sparklyr, but if that is not possible, native R code is fine (thanks to the spark_apply function).

Comment: The `cut()` function is one way to bin the data.

Comment: `dplyr::cut` would help simplify some of the code. Though you will have to explain why you need to generate the code using a script. The OP is unclear about how the cut points are calculated for each variable.

Comment: I looked into the cut function but had two concerns: 1) it converted the data to a factor (really more of an annoyance than a problem since as.numeric can fix that), and 2) the intervals must always be open/closed on the same side. That is, there is no way for it to handle the example given above:
(-Inf, 0] -> 0
[0, 628) -> 1
...
[4819, Inf] -> 4

Note the the intervals are not always open/closed on the same side.

Comment: Amongst the several hundred variables are there likely to be commonalities?  I see that you say they are not all the same but are there at least groupings?  I would think that a combination of `case_when` and `mutate_at` (new version `across`) might at least be more efficient and be less than 30,000 lines of code.

Comment: Unfortunately there are not that many groupings. Since the original data is continuous, the ranges are fairly unique for all of them. They all start with 0 as a lower boundary and end with infinity as an upper boundary, but between those two it is very rare for the cut points to be the same. Many of the variables have cut points using decimals, not just integers.

Comment: @RobertWilson Sorry I forgot to respond to your post. I have a table that has these cut points. They can be changed from time to time as the underlying distribution changes. For my purpose here it doesn't really matter how the underlying cut points are computed, merely how they are applied. The reason a script is used to generate this code is because I'm lazy and don't want to make it by hand for hundreds of variables. (The end code would be the same regardless)

Comment: @ChuckP, however, maybe something like
df <- df %>% mutate(myVar = case_when(myVar >= 0 & myVar < 628 ~ 1, ...))

Comment: @ChuckP, your suggestion led me to the correct answer. I've rewritten the code to use mutate and case_when. If you want to create an answer out of your suggestion I'll accept it so you can get credit.

Comment: I'm good glad I was a little helpful.